# Application configuration is incorrect????What to do?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, x86, 64-bit, manifest

i run my application in visual studio 2010 express and when i run,it gives me an error that:-
"the application has failed to start because application configuration is incorrect.Review the manifest file for possible errors"

My manifest file looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.6195" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.6195" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file contains references to Visual Studio 2008 runtime, but you're compiling it in VS2010. That seems to be the reason for the error.

Comment: Have you tried to build the application without the manifest file?

Comment: ya i deleted the manifest and again tried to run it,it gives the same error

Comment: What are manifest file settings in linker properties? Do you have both VS2008 and 2010 installed on the same PC?

Comment: If your application has .lib or .dll projects, make sure that all they are built with VS2010.

Comment: my .lib are build with VS2010 itself....by manifest file setting which option do u mean:-Generate manifest=YES(/MANIFEST),Manifest file=$(IntDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).intermediate.manifest,allow isolation=Yes (/ALLOWISOLATION),Enable user account=Yes (/MANIFESTUAC:),UAC execution level=asInvoker (/level='asInvoker'),UAC By pass protection=No (/uiAccess='false')